# dynamic creation of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a coverflow using the plugin locate here: http://vanderlee.github.io/coverflow/

All I have to do is this:

```
<div class="coverflow">
    <div class="cover">A</div>
    <div class="cover">B</div>
    ...
    <div class="cover">Y</div>
    <div class="cover">Z</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.coverflow').coverflow();
    });
</script>
```

This works fine for manually created elements but when doing something like the following:

```
var el = {
    newDiv: $("<div>", { class: "cover newDiv"}),
    newElt: $("<div>", { class: "cover newDiv"})
}

$("#preview-coverflow").append(el.newDiv);
$("#preview-coverflow").append(el.newElt);
```

my divs are displayed in a vertical fashion, rather than horizontal. My question is whether there is any difference between the two forms of element creation? In both cases I am (trying) to create empty div and append to the parent. Am I doing anything wrong?

In my style sheet, just to see my empty divs:

```
.newDiv { 
    background-color:red
}
```

Comment: One shouldn't give the same "id" value to more than one element.

Comment: Thanks now fixed. I created that ID for illustration. the problem persists though.

Comment: It should be managed through css class by giving `position as absolute` in addtion to `refresh` call, please see my work around in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<style>
    .newDiv {
        background: gold;
        position: absolute;
        width: 320px;
        height: 320px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.coverflow').coverflow();
        addNewTest();// test call here
    });

function addNewTest(){
    var el = {
        newDiv: $("<div>", { class: "cover newDiv"}),
        newElt: $("<div>", { class: "cover newDiv"})
    }

    $("#preview-coverflow").append(el.newDiv, el.newElt).coverflow('refresh');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Venkata. I needed to set the positioning to absolute and refresh the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the .coverflow() needs to be run after the elements have been added.

In the console, after dynamically adding the html, just try running

```
$('.coverflow').coverflow('refresh');
```

If that seems to fix the issue, then look at implementing it after you add the new elements.

---

Didnt notice the plugin has a refresh function to it, using the refresh should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `refresh` method after you add new elements

```
$('.coverflow').coverflow('refresh');
```

From Docs:

> **refresh**
>
> ```
> Redraw the covers. You shouldn't ever need to do this unless you are adding or removing 
> covers or changing the covers yourself.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

try this without any plugin for dynamic creation of elements. Its pure javascript and JQuery:

```
<script>

    var myDivs = ""; 

    for(var i=0; i <10; i++)
    {
        myDivs+= "<div class='cover'></div>";
    }

    $(".coverflow").html(myDivs);

<script>
```

I think it clear your concept. Hope this works.